# SwiftUI Dynamic Image Sizing

Tags: swiftui

**Problem:**
I have a `View` that I needed to place multiple (2) views that contained: 1 `Image` + 1 `Text`. I decided to break that up into a `ClickableImageAndText` structure that I called on twice. This works perfectly if the image is a set size (64x64) but I would like this to work on all size classes. Now, I know that I can do the following:

```swift
if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
    Text("Compact")
} else {
    Text("Regular")
}
```

but I am asking for both **Different Size Classes** and **Same Size Classes** such as the iPhone X and iPhone 13 which are the same.

**Question:**
How do I alter the image for dynamic phone sizes (iPhone X, 13, 13 pro, etc) so it looks appropriate for all measurements?

**Code:**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ClickableImageAndText: View {
    let image: String
    let text: String
    let tapAction: (() -> Void)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
            Text(text)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            tapAction()
        }
    }
}

struct InitialView: View {
    
    var topView: some View {
        Image("Empty_App_Icon")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }
    
    var bottomView: some View {
        VStack {
            ClickableImageAndText(
                image: "Card_Icon",
                text: "View Your Memories") {
                    print("Tapped on View Memories")
                }
                .padding(.bottom)
            ClickableImageAndText(
                image: "Camera",
                text: "Add Memories") {
                    print("Tapped on Add Memories")
                }
                .padding(.top)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GradientView()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                topView
                Spacer()
                bottomView
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InitialView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        InitialView()
    }
}
```

**Image Note:**
My background includes a `GradientView` that I have since removed (thanks @lorem ipsum). If you so desire, here is the `GradientView` code but it is unnecessary for the problem above.

**GradientView.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct GradientView: View {
    let firstColor = Color(uiColor: UIColor(red: 127/255, green: 71/255, blue: 221/255, alpha: 1))
    let secondColor = Color(uiColor: UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 174/255, blue: 23/255, alpha: 1))
    let startPoint = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let endPoint = UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    
    
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient:
            Gradient(
                colors: [firstColor, secondColor]),
                startPoint: startPoint,
                endPoint: endPoint)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct GradientView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GradientView()
    }
}
```

[image: Set 64x64 size]

**Effort 1:**
Added a `GeometryReader` to my `ClickableImageAndText` structure and the view is automatically changed incorrectly.

```
struct ClickableImageAndText: View {
    let image: String
    let text: String
    let tapAction: (() -> Void)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            VStack {
                Image(image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                Text(text)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                tapAction()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Effort 1]

**Effort 2:**
Added a `GeometryReader` as directed by @loremipsum's [deleted] answer and the content is still being pushed; specifically, the `topView` is being push to the top and the `bottomView` is taking the entire space with the addition of the `GeometryReader`.

```
struct ClickableImageAndText: View {
    let image: String
    let text: String
    let tapAction: (() -> Void)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            VStack {
                Image(image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                //You can do this and set strict size constraints
                //.frame(minWidth: 64, maxWidth: 128, minHeight: 64,  maxHeight: 128, alignment: .center)
                //Or this to set it to be percentage of the size of the screen
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2, alignment: .center)
                Text(text)
                
            }.foregroundColor(.white)
            //Everything moves to the left because the `View` expecting a size vs stretching.
            //If yo want the entire width just set the View with on the outer most View
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, alignment: .center)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            tapAction()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Effort 2]

Comment: Use Geometry reader and percentages based size

Comment: `GeometryReader` removes the `Spacer`s which I need to maintain my current structure.

Comment: @loremipsum added images/efforts for this as well

Comment: @impression7vx For `"How do I alter the image for dynamic phone sizes ... so it looks appropriate for all measurements?"`: What do you mean? How will you adjust for different sizes, by size class or by relative width of screen / parent view?

Comment: `"but I am asking for both Different Size Classes and Same Size Classes such as the iPhone X and iPhone 13 which are the same"` - Both! It seems size classes are by `.compact` and `.regular` comparisons but I was also wanting relativeness.

Comment: All you likely have to do to "fix" my deleted answer is add the `height` to the `VStack`'s frame. Something like this `.frame(width: geo.size.width , height: geo.size.height, alignment: .center)`.Like I said in the comments the `GeometryReader` keeps the `Stack` from taking all the space, you just have to tell it to stretch. It is hard to help when you haven't provided everything that is needed to reproduce.

Comment: So if you copy and paste what you have provided in a blank project. You get the exact behavior you have?  Give it a try... Create a blank project and copy and paste what you have provided. See if it even compiles, let alone mimic the behavior

Comment: My apologies; I kept in the `GradientView`... LOL if that is your only complaint . Everything else worked like a charm. Removing the `GradientView` (mind you, as the name implies, is simply the background) and resides outside of the `VStack`. I'll remove it now 

Comment: Like I said before I don't see the point in this. Your images don't exist, in a blank project. you need to replicate it some other way. What is your goal with this? If your code works perfectly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Luckily I have been in this community a while and have appreciated others' commen sense and ability to make adjustments (e.g. `Image(systemName: "rectangle")`). I hope you take me as a learning lesson and don't scare away the new programmers who hope to one day thrive in this community. Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution is to use screen bounds (which will be different for different phones) as reference value to calculate per-cent-based dynamic size for image. And to track device orientation changes we wrap our calculations into `GeometryReader`.

Note: I don't have your images, so added white borders for demo purpose

[image: demo]

```
struct ClickableImageAndText: View {
    let image: String
    let text: String
    let tapAction: (() -> Void)

    @State private var size = CGFloat(32) // some minimal initial value (not 0)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                // .border(Color.white)            // << for demo !!
                .background(GeometryReader { _ in
                    // GeometryReader is needed to track orientation changes
                    let sizeX = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
                    let sizeY = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

                    // Screen bounds is needed for reference dimentions, and use
                    // it to calculate needed size as per-cent to be dynamic
                    let width = min(sizeX, sizeY)
                    Color.clear                             // % (whichever you want)
                        .preference(key: ViewWidthKey.self, value: width * 0.2) 
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewWidthKey.self) {
                    self.size = max($0, size)
                }
                .frame(width: size, height: size)

            Text(text)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            tapAction()
        }
    }
}
```